# Problems in nodejs API requests with Reactjs application and Nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I'm developing a full-stack application, where the frontend was made in `Reactjs` and there is an application in `nodejs` for requests via API (express). To make the frontend available to users, I'm using the `Nginx` service.

I'm compiling the entire application in an **Ubuntu Docker container**, to later deploy it on Google Cloud Run. So far, I managed to make the frontend of the site available on port 80 of my container and I can access it in the browser through the link `http://localhost:80`.

However, the React application is not able to make requests to the API in nodejs, I am getting the error in the image below:

[image]

However, when I run the same request command (curl http://0.0.0.0:5555/getDocuments?col=houses_test) inside my container (via `docker run -it`), I get the expected response without errors.

This is my **project tree**:

```
My-Project
 ┣ backend
 ┃ ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┣ index.js
 ┃ ┣ package-lock.json
 ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┣ frontend
 ┃ ┣ build
 ┃ ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┣ public
 ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┗ yarn.lock
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┗ nginx.conf
```

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
# Image definition
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /app

# Dependencies installation
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install curl gnupg systemctl -y

# Nodejs installation
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt update -y && apt install nodejs -y

# Yarn installation
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt update -y && apt install yarn -y

# Backend build
COPY backend/package.json ./backend/
RUN cd backend && npm i
COPY ./backend/ ./backend/

# Frontend build
COPY frontend/package.json ./frontend/
RUN cd frontend && yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY ./frontend/ ./frontend/
RUN cd frontend && yarn build

# Nginx installation and config
RUN 134 | 2 | apt install nginx -y
RUN mkdir /var/www/127.0.0.1
RUN chmod 755 -R /var/www/127.0.0.1/
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/127.0.0.1
RUN unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/127.0.0.1 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
RUN cp -r frontend/build/* /var/www/127.0.0.1
CMD ["systemctl" "start" "nginx"]
```

This is my **nginx.conf**:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/127.0.0.1;
    index index.html;
}
```

And I'm serving the API requests in **React** with:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://0.0.0.0:5555`
})
```

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Keep in mind that your browser (which makes the requests) runs on your host, not in the container. Where and how is your Express server running?

Comment: Hi @Phil, thanks for the reply! The Express server is running inside the container, for now I'm starting it manually with `node index.js` when I access the container shell with `docker run -it`.

Comment: The `CMD` at the end of your Dockerfile almost certainly won't work; can you set it to something like `CMD node index.js` instead, so the container actually runs your service?  It's not clear from that screen shot what the actual error is.  If you can set up the Nginx as a reverse proxy to both services, you should be able to avoid encoding any particular host name into your image build, which might help this issue.

Comment: Hi @David! Yes, the `CMD` is not working =(
But the error is that the React application can't make requests to my Nodejs server, it's like it doesn't exist. Can you provide an example about the "Nginx as a reverse proxy", please?

Comment: If the Express server is also running in the container, you need to forward the appropriate host port so your browser can reach it, eg `-p 5555:5555`

Comment: Important to keep in mind that is not recommended to keep multiple apps inside the same container. You could create two different images, one for React App with nginx and another with your api express.

Comment: @Takehana I did it because I want to deploy my site on Google Cloud Run, and it's not possible to deploy a `docker-compose` architecture there. Do you see a better way to do this?

Comment: Could always deploy the front-end to Firebase Hosting. See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/integrate/using-gcp-services#web

Comment: Thaks for help, guys! I followed the tips from this video and finished my application! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UobUxpW6WQ&t=392s&ab_channel=MongoDB

Answer (score -1):

your `Dockerfile` is missing `EXPOSE` with application port (80).
The `EXPOSE` instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime

Docker docs official link https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Example:

```
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: _"The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port"_

Comment: I did not realize he tries to keep React App and Express Api on the same docker.

Comment: Wouldn't matter where it was running. Adding `EXPOSE` does not do anything on its own, you still need the appropriate port mapping option when running the container

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! @Phil said everything!